# How to restart dotnetcore 2 C# Console app

Tags: c#, .net-core

How should I restart a dotnetcore C# console app?

I have tried suggestions found for C# console apps, but doesnt work for dotnetcore.

(This is not asp.net, which is where so many dotnetcore answers point)

Comment: What do you mean by restarting? You want the app to close and launch again?

Comment: Yes, The closing part is trivial, so having a new instance launch I guess.

Comment: What you can do is start the new instance of the app right before exiting. Maybe this can help : https://medium.com/@equiman/run-a-command-in-external-terminal-with-net-core-cc24e3cc9839

Comment: If you publish your app as self-contained, I believe all previous tricks should apply. "I have tried suggestion found" is never part of a good question, as you need to be very specific on what you have tried.

Comment: @SteelToe Because I want to do this programatically... Without me being there to do it.

Comment: Why not just create a new process that launches your app using shell commands and then exit the current program after it launches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so im going to assume in this answer that it is ok with you if your program will start a new instance of your program and then close itself.

Here we go:

Since a dotnet console app can be started from the console, I think the best way to start a new instance of your console application would be thorugh using shell commands. To run shell commands from your program, add this helper class to your application: (If you are using windows instead of mac/linux, please see the end of this post)

```
  using System;
  using System.Diagnostics;
public static class ShellHelper
{
    public static string Shell(this string cmd)
    {
        var escapedArgs = cmd.Replace("\"", "\\\"");

        var process = new Process()
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "/bin/bash",
                Arguments = $"-c \"{escapedArgs}\"",
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
            }
        };
        process.Start();
        string result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        process.WaitForExit();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Then since this is a extension method, just import it and then create a string with the command to restart your app and then use the `Shell()` method.

So if you are in development and you normally start your app by running `dotnet run` then make sure you are in the proper directory and then just use this line of code `"dotnet run".Shell();`

If you want to get the feedback from running the command then just assign the return value like this `string result = "dotnet run".Shell();`

Then once you have started the new process you just exit your current program by either returning on your main method etc.

Please Note: The above code is for mac/linux, If you are on windows, then the following two lines of the above code:

```
FileName = "/bin/bash",
Arguments = $"-c \"{escapedArgs}\"",
```

Should be replaced with:

```
FileName = "cmd.exe",
Arguments = $"/c \"{escapedArgs}\"",
```

Comment: Running my app from dotnet is run with this command: `dotnet bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\BinanceBase.dll`. I try that but get "The system cannot find the file specified" as an error.

Comment: I would reccomend specifying the full path to BinanceBase.dll instead of a relative path.

Comment: So the problem was that the above answer was for mac / linux, but was testing this on Windows. filename needed to be cmd.exe and arguements start with /c not -c in windows. Made those changes and it works now, thanks.

Comment: You have WaitForExit() in there so your current program won't exit until the new instance exits.. potentially resulting in a stack overflow.